# How do I get my Panasonic Lumix DMC-LZ20 lens diameter?

Tags: panasonic-lumix, filter-diameter

I'm new with my camera and I was wondering what size filters to get.

Comment: Are there threads at the front of the lens that would accept? The reason I ask is that I can find no evidence that the lens can accept an external filter.

Comment: Is it possible the filter mounts on the hood?  http://forums.steves-digicams.com/panasonic-leica/36281-72mm-uv-filter-dmc-lz20.html#b

Comment: Also as low tech as it seems, you can actually use larger filters just by holding them in front of the lens (I have been known to do this when playing with grads and did not get ready in time).

Answer (score 2):

You have to look for the ø symbol in the objective or the number behind the frontal cup of your camera. However the simplest thing to do is to use a ruler and measure from the inner edge of your camera. Take the maximum diameter you'll find and than search for the filter that most fit the measure. If you post a photo with a ruler near the objective I can measure it for you.

Comment: There is no thread for a filter in the lens of this camera. What do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: I have simply answerd the question, you have already said the major possibilities to do that. In a camera without filter holder you can think to attach permanetly in some way a Cokin P-Holder but I think you can't do that in the Lumix LZ20...

Answer (score 1):

There is no thread for a filter in the lens of Lumix LZ20 camera.

Your best option is to hold a filter in front of the lens with your fingers. Another option is to search for a filter that has outer diameter exactly match the outmost part of the lens and fasten the filter with tape onto the lens. Though this latter method will quite likely lead to vignetting in photos when at the wide end of the zoom. Also the old lens cap is perhaps not as tight fit on the filter as it should / too tight fit.